# How to pass data from angular 6 to Nodejs?

Tags: html, node.js, angular, angular6

Im using angular 6 & I have never used angular before. I need to send data to nodejs server. Im using the following code in angular function

```
     import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
     import { HttpClient,HttpHeaders  } from '@angular/common/http';

      const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
       };


     fun_add(Id, cat) {
     return this.http.post('/go', data, 
      httpOptions).subscribe(result => {
        console.log(result);
       }, error => console.log('There was an error: '));
      }
```

In my nodejs,

```
    app.post('/go', function (req, res) {
      console.log("hi");
      })
```

But I couldnt go to the server. Im getting the error msg 'there was an error'.
can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: `http.post('http://localhost:port/go'` otherwise it is no valid URL

Comment: It should be valid, can you show us network traffic?

Comment: @trichetriche — Relative URLs have been supported since before I'd even heard of the WWW.

Comment: @Quentin that's cool and all, but Angular probably expects HTTP url and not relative ones. Besides, Using `/go` isn't really that relative, it will try to get the root of whatever the folder is ...Not only that's not very clear, but that's also very random

Comment: @trichetriche — Angular's `http.post` expects a URL. A relative URL is fine. `/go` is an absolute path, but it is a relative URL. It's perfectly clear (and very useful for writing code which works in (for example) development and production environments) and not even slightly random.

Comment: @Quentin and How is Angular supposed to know that that absolute path is the server ? How can it knows the port it's running on ?

Comment: @trichetriche I have tried giving that also. still not working

Comment: @trichetriche — Angular and the underlying `XMLHttpRequest` object it calls runs in the JavaScript environment hosted by a webpage. Relative URLs are relative to the URL of that page.

Comment: @BhavaniSankar on which port and domain is your server running ? `localhost:9876`?

Comment: @Quentin very good to know, thank you !

Comment: @BhavaniSankar are you seeing `hi` in your NodeJS console ?

Comment: @trichetriche localhost:4200

Comment: @Quentin no Im not seeing the hi msg

Comment: @BhavaniSankar did you try calling with `http.post('http://localhost:4200/go'` ? Is your server running ?

Comment: @BhavaniSankar — Where are you looking for it?

Comment: In my cmd prompt @Quentin

Comment: I really think maybe this is a cors issue, as the angular and NodeJS server has different port. Can you check adding cors? But I will request you to check the network panel. It will give you the necessary information.

Comment: You don't even check what `error` is.

Comment: this.getAuthToken is not a function is the error.. @AritraChakraborty

Answer (score 1):

You never send a response (e.g. with `res.send()`), so the server gets the request and sits there.

Meanwhile, the client waits, and waits, and eventually times out and throws an error because the server never responded.

Comment: If it was the case he would have seen the result of `console.log("hi");`

Comment: @trichetriche — They only reported what they saw in the browser.

Comment: @trichetriche — There is no statement, one way or the other, as to what the output on the console from Node.js is. That is a fact, not an assumption.

Comment: My bad, `there was an error` is the error caught. Removing my previous comment !

Comment: @quentin I have tried sending response too. Still its not working.

Comment: this.getAuthToken is not a function is the error. @quentin .. Do you know how it should be solved?

Comment: this.getAuthToken is not a function is the error.Do you know how it should be solved? @trichetriche

Comment: This is  completely unrelated to your issue. And no, you didn't provide the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
    let api_url = 'http:localhost:portNumber'

   fun_add(Id, cat) {
      return this.http.post(api_url+'/go', data, 
          httpOptions).subscribe(result => {
            console.log(result);
       }, error => console.log('There was an error: '));
    }
```

Comment: Are you able you to hit API? @BhavaniSankar
Try sending response back as  
         res.status(200);
            res.json({
                success: "Data"
            });

Comment: still no.. Is there any other way to send datas from angular to nodejs?  Vishal Hasnani

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in component

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient);
```

It's Working.